# How to exclude specific row from filtering in grepl in R?

Tags: r, grepl

I have following dataset:

[image]

I would want to filter out the rows that have year 2019 apart from row "30.12.2019 bis 05.01.2020".

I tried to do it with grepl fiction, but I don't know how the exclamation is working there.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Try `df[!grepl("2019$", df$b), ]`, where the `$` in the regex means *end-of-line*

Comment: I believe Andre's comment is the right answer. For future questions, *"tried to do it with grepl"*, it is often beneficial (both for you and for us) if you include the code that failed. In this way, we can both see effort/intent as well as correcting your mistakes in the code that you used. Often answers use none of the code in the question, but when able I prefer to show exactly where the mistake/misunderstanding was made in the original code before suggesting an alternate code path. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I meant. I wanted to delete rows that contain "2019" but besides the exact rows that are "30.12.2019 bis 05.01.2020". Your solution deletes all the 2019, also the one's I want to keep.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.